# Tips on finding villages easily

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can anyone make a list of tips and methods to find a village in vanilla Minecraft Java edition 1.16 without using cheats, any third party software. I have searched but I want a more clean and reliable list with tips and tricks that work and it would be better if more are there.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Without the use of in-game cheats, I could only recommend a few things;

1. (direct method) Search in the suitable biomes:
   Villages can generate in the following biomes; plains, savannah, desert, taiga, and tundra. Search within these biomes, and you may be lucky and find a village within them.
2. (indirect method) Use one of the explorer maps/treasure maps:
   Although no explorer or treasure maps actually leads directly to villages, there is a potential possiblity that a village may exist around the displayed boundaries of the maps, and traveling to the displayed areas of these maps mean you'll need to explore the world along the way (meaning more possibilities to bump into a village by chance).
3. (the out-of-game cheaty method) Use the Village locater on the Chunkbase website:
   Although this is the most cheaty option given, it technically isn't cheating in-game but rather outside of it since it's a website, however if you feel like this method goes too far with cheating then I wouldn't recommend it. Chunkbase is a website that works for various updates and editions of Minecraft, and can detect and displays the locations of biomes, slime chunks, villages, dungeons, mineshafts, strongholds, and various other generated structures for any world seed. If you'd like to use this website then I'll link you to it;

https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/village-finder

Edit: There's also another way to legitimately locate a village; specifically the taiga village type.
If you're able to see tall trails of smoke in the sky while wandering through a taiga, then you've found a taiga village as they're one of the only village types with naturally generated campfires, so their campfire smoke reveals their village location easier than most other village types.

Comment: I don't want to use any third party software such as chunkbase. I want to locate it during speedruns.

Comment: Indeed, I personally wouldn't recommend the Chunkbase website option for situations where you'd want a 100% legitimate world/run, though I felt like I should mention its possibilities nonetheless.

Comment: Hmmm, so any other tips like exploring in a manner which makes it easier to bump into villages?

Comment: A little while after posting my answer, I remembered one last method. An hour or so ago I got to include it as an edit at the end of the first post.

Comment: Thank you, I find this helpful and I have upvoted it but I will put the tick mark once I verify it